# Symfony2 ObjectChoiceList Selected correct option

Tags: forms, api, symfony

I'm on a Symfony2 application consuming REST API (no Doctrine entities).

I have on a form type:
($this->regionService is a service for retrieve from the API all the available regions)

```
$regionChoiceList = new ObjectChoiceList($this->regionService->getAll(), 'name', array(), null, 'id');

$builder->add('region', 'choice', array(
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'choice_list' => $regionChoiceList
            ))
```

Creating new entity all works fine. When I try to edit the object with this type I don't have selected the correct option.
The serialized object is correct, leaving an example of the object serialized from JSON response:

```
Object:
  "name" = "blahblah"
  "etc..."
  "region"(Region Object): 
    "name" = "name region"
    "id"   = identifier region
```

Answer (score 1):

You may replace the Region in the list returned by the RegionService with the one contained in the Object entity.

It seems that the instance must be the same to make symfony select the corret option.

Comment: The RegionService returns the same object

Comment: I’m having the exact same problem: I expected the form to select the correct option based on the value of the property at `$valuePath` (`id`in this example), but it actually compares the objects, so two different instances with the same properties won’t match.

Comment: I.e. if you `var_dump( $this->regionService->getAll() )` and `var_dump` the form data, you might get `object(Region)#42 (4) { ["id":protected]=> int(1)` and `object(Region)#314 (4) { ["id":protected]=> int(1)`: they’re different instances even if they have the same properties.